# Is it dangerous to have Tor exit node?

Tags: tor, government

If I buy VPS and create Tor exit node there what would happen if someone did bad thing using my exit node? (terrorism, hacking goverment sites etc) 
VPS provider will share information about me to FBI or another goverment organizations or just will send abuse and block my VPS because it's obviously that I'm just an operator of exit node, not terrorist?

Comment: This probably depends on the country you're in, and the laws and treaties surrounding each country involved. Depending on your involvement, in some cases, you may be introduced to fun activities such as surfing, and chicken meat sandwiches.

Comment: You're asking about the legal ramifications of hosting a service that is misused. Asking us to comment on the actions or potential actions of any third party is directly asking for speculation, which is something we avoid.

Comment: The TOR project as an [excellent legal FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/eff/tor-legal-faq.html.en) on their web-page, which tries to answer this question and provide some additional advice. Summary: governments and FBI know about and understand TOR, so you'll most likely only be blocked by some services, but technically they might ask you for data about the TOR node.

Answer (score 5):

Some people [ran into big trouble](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20140701/18013327753/tor-nodes-declared-illegal-austria.shtml) for what was done with their exit node. Others [got away with it](http://boingboing.net/2015/08/04/what-happened-when-the-fbi-sub.html). It really depends on the jurisdiction, but also the context, and in particular the willingness of either law enforcement agencies or the privacy-defending organisations to turn a specific case into a story that will elicit emotional response from the general public and thus help in pursuing a political agenda.

So basically it depends. A lot.

Comment: it DEPENDS and DEFINES about how you're setting a VPS up. If you're **entitled** to take **ALL** responsibilities for an actions done from your VPS IP - you're *clinically insane* to use such kind of service. If the ToS and EULA are sane, then you're **not** guilt because of "*not proven guilty*"

Answer (score -3):

Don't host an exit-node on boxes/property on YOUR NAME. You should remain anonymous when involving yourself with this. Atleast in the U.S. and maybe the European Union so far I'm concerned.

Comment: Downvoted because of knowing some facts that are prooving you wrong

Comment: Have not been really clear on this, if you want to avoid ALL possible trouble that might occur you should remain anonymous.